# Wordpress Acf Fields not showing in frond end

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have used ACF plugin for creating new fields in my test page.
Firstly I have added a custom field then arrange it to test page. In that particular test page, I am added text for fields & then published.But Which is not showing on my front page. Please help me to find an answer
These are screenshots: 1. http://prntscr.com/g0u29f
2.http://prntscr.com/g0u00d

Comment: Add some code so we can help.

Comment: I didn't  write any code . I have did these from my admin panel

Comment: add some frontend code which you are using to display on frontend

Comment: Can you please help me to find a solution

Comment: Try to use something like this <?php echo get_field('field_name'); ?>

Comment: Or yiu can try <?php echo get_field( 'field_name', $post_id ); ?> where $post_id is current page id

Comment: I am new in WordPress. So can you please explain to me where I want to add these code?

Comment: Did you created new template for this page ? or you want to display this ACF to every page?

Comment: I didn't create any template & also I want only this to that particular page it self.

Comment: First You have to create new template for this page then you can do anything for this specific page only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the value you can add `<?php the_field('test', get_the_ID()); ?>` to your `index.php` or `frontpage.php`.

Or if you would just like to retrieve the value and assign it to a variable you could do it like `<?php $test = get_the_field('test', get_the_ID(); ?>`

`the_field()` takes the name of the field and the id of the post or page.

`the_field()` displays the value while `get_field()` returns the value to be assigned.